# FPDF library "Output" doesn't work?

Tags: php, fpdf

My problem with `[FPDF]` library is the next:

```
$pdf->Output("doc1.pdf","D");
```

In the above example I replaced the `D` with `I` or `S` or `F` the result is always the same: a popup appears to save or open the file.

I want to save it without a popup into a specific directory.

Comment: Do you want to save it on the client on the server?

Answer (score 2):

Have you added an header which tells the browser the output is an pdf file?
Try:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

Just before the output.

Answer (score 2):

maybe use this

```
$pdf->Output('D:/example2.pdf','F');
```

F = save to a local file with the name given by name
D:/example2.pdf = dest folder and  name of file ,,,,

thats it, save it without a windows popup appears

Answer (score 0):

if you read the documentation at http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/output.htm
says that dest should be first and the name second, although all of them are optional.

```
$pdf->Output("D","example2");
```

you shouldnt name your file .pdf because it will add it when you download it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you didn't output absolutely nothing before calling the Output (neither a whitespace, tab or anything) or the browser will just go nuts. Pay special attention at your includes, if any.